# How to update a relationship between two tables with SQLite and OrmLite in Android?

Tags: java, sqlite, crud

I'm doing CRUD's using a SQLite database with OrmLite. Also, using DAO and Repository pattern.

Right now, I'm trying to get the relation between two tables, where a PK is a PK of other table. In that case I make the relation like in the documentation, doing a ForeignColumn true and give it the column name, and also creating the getters and setters.

All good from there, but when I go to the repository, it doesn't have the same type of data (in the update repository, it needs an int ID and an object that will be updated), but this is weird because I just get the full object not the ID or int of that object. I know that it can't be compatible with it, but I don't know how to solve it. I included a couple of images for reference.

Using this as PK and also is part of PK in another table. This is a relative to DoorGroups, and Readers is the relational table.

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, columnName="doorGroupId")
private DoorGroups doorGroups ;
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, columnName="readerId")
private Readers readers ;

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
//Where the FK comes from
ForeignCollection<DoorGroups> doorGroupsForeignCollection;
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
//Where the FK comes from
ForeignCollection<Readers> readersForeignCollection;

public DoorGroups getDoorGroups() {
  return doorGroups;
}

public void setDoorGroups(DoorGroups doorGroups) {
  this.doorGroups = doorGroups;
}

public ForeignCollection<Readers> getReadersForeignCollection() {
  return readersForeignCollection;
}

public ForeignCollection<DoorGroups> getDoorGroupsForeignCollection() {
  return doorGroupsForeignCollection;
}
```

But in the repository, if I get update method, it cant receive an int arg => (See photo)

[image issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LUC3.png)